# What is the difference between Android API "31" and Android API "S"?

Tags: android, api

I'm wondering what the difference is between Android API "S" and Android API "31" in Android Studio. Isn't API Level 31 supposed to be "S"?

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you open up your SDK Manager, do you see entries for both "Android 12.0 (S)" and "Android S Preview"?

Comment: Thank you very much @CommonsWare. In the SDK Manager, when checking "Show Package Details" the "S Preview" appeared. So in the AVD Manager API "S" corresponds to the S Preview. Issue solved! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) for the hint. In the SDK Manager, when checking "Show Package Details" the "S Preview" appeared. So in the AVD Manager API "S" corresponds to "S Preview".